# How to stop function propagation after first click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, stoppropagation

I have some click function... whole action is fine but if i fastly doubleclick at call button some elements generates two times. Can you tell me how to stop function propagation after first click? Much thx for help, and this is my code:

```
$('#start_panel ul li').click(function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass('eng')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('ger')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('pln')){
       ...
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: If not .one() pass closure to click that maintains the nr of clicks

Comment: If you use `on()` to bind the click, you can also use `off()` to unbind it until the function completes.

Comment: so, why i'v got a down vote? i'm asking for the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var clicked = false;
$('#start_panel ul li').click(function(event){
   if (clicked) return;
   clicked = true;
```

Or use the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function (slightly different : now only one click *per li element* will be handled) :

```
 $('#start_panel ul li').one('click', function(event){
```

Comment: +1 finally an answer that actually addresses the problem properly.

Comment: the `.one()` option helps. but if i have a `.live('click',...` ?

Comment: @Jack "finally" ? This was the first answer.

Comment: @dystroy couldn't tell because the answers of same score are not sorted on anything :)

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski What's your version of jquery ?

Comment: i have the new'st version - 1.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var myClicker = function(event){
    var self = event.currentTarget;
    if($(self).hasClass('eng')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(self).hasClass('ger')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(self).hasClass('pln')){
       ...
    }
    $(self).one('click', myClicker);
});
$('#start_panel ul li').one('click', myClicker);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var i=0;
$('#start_panel ul li').click(function(event){
 if(i==1){
  i=0;
 return false;
  }
if($(this).hasClass('eng')){
   ...
}
else if($(this).hasClass('ger')){
   ...
}
else if($(this).hasClass('pln')){
   ...
}
 i++;


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear previous request use `Stop(true,true)`

```
$('#start_panel ul li').stop(true,true).click(function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass('eng')){
        ...
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('ger')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('pln')){
       ...
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Are you sure stop() is'nt really for the $.fx animation queue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind the click event after the first click:

```
$('#start_panel ul li').click(function(event){
    $(this).unbind('click'); 
    if($(this).hasClass('eng')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('ger')){
       ...
    }
    else if($(this).hasClass('pln')){
       ...
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```